# rename batch files (delete some symbols in names) (python/matlab/shell)

Tags: python, c++, matlab, shell, rename

I want to rename lots of files in a folder. All files start with `tr_+number+samp_+missing symbols`

From:

```
tr_000_samp_833f.bin
tr_001_samp_889f.bin
tr_002_samp_12f0.bin
tr_003_samp_320v.bin
```

To:

```
tr_000_samp.bin
tr_001_samp.bin
tr_002_samp.bin
tr_003_samp.bin
```

Any language is ok. MATLAB, python c++ or shell.
Thabk you so much!

Comment: Please select one language and show where your problem is.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1136/batch-renaming-files

Comment: *"Any language is ok"* Hum... Aren't you afraid some funny guy will post assembly code?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the names have fixed length, and providing the Matlab steps.

First get, the list of files in folder:

```
dirc = dir();
```

Now get only the names matching some criteria:

```
rename_list = {};
for ii=1:length(dirc)
  if(~isempty(strfind(dirc(ii).name,'tr_')) &&...
     ~isempty(strfind(dirc(ii).name,'samp_')) &&...
     ~isempty(strfind(dirc(ii).name,'.bin')))
```

Copy the file with its new name:

```
       name = dirc(ii).name;
       copyfile(name,name([1:11,end-3,end])
```

Delete old file (If you must and if you're brave enough)

```
       delete(name)
```

Close the loops:

```
   end
end
```